# rust / SWC plugin / how to test jsx?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, swc

I'm trying to create a plugin by doing the documentation - https://swc.rs/docs/plugin/ecmascript/getting-started

I have simplified the example. The plugin doesn't change anything.

```
test!(
    Default::default(),
    |_| as_folder(TransformVisitor),
    boo,
    r#"foo === bar;"#,
    r#"foo === bar;"#
);
```

run "cargo test" - Good!

Test to validate jsx:

```
test!(
    Default::default(),
    |_| as_folder(TransformVisitor),
    boo,
    r#"<main></main>"#,
    r#"<main></main>"#
);
```

run "cargo test" - error **Expression expected**

How do I do a jsx validation test?

Here is a link to the "test" macro documentation. I don't understand what to do
https://rustdoc.swc.rs/swc_core/ecma/transforms/testing/macro.test.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see on the [SWC Playground](https://play.swc.rs/?version=1.3.51&code=H4sIAAAAAAAAA7PJTczMs7PRB1MA%2BfIcmg0AAAA%3D&config=H4sIAAAAAAAAA1WPSw7DIAwF9zkF8rrbdtE79BAWdSIifrKJVBTl7iUE0maH3xsz8jooBbNoeKq1PMsQkYX4nEsi2Sf8lARIOxTNJia49XaWvRrRCtVoOxpIyBOluiX3hoMNQajjLXPGmzH%2FC3VwkUnkCu4o%2BsnSVTc0JbjwXmrZDkk50qF%2FwA%2FqsvNjMPLqm4kXGrYvhlQioBQBAAA%3D) that `<main></main>` is not valid syntax, at least not by default.

The parameter you're passing as `Default::default()` is the [`Syntax`](https://rustdoc.swc.rs/swc_ecma_parser/enum.Syntax.html) configuration. You should instead specify that you're expecting JSX, something like this (untested):

```
use swc_ecma_parser::{EsConfig, Syntax};

test!(
    Syntax::Es(EsConfig {
        jsx: true,
        ..Default::default()
    }),
    |_| as_folder(TransformVisitor),
    boo,
    r#"<main></main>"#,
    r#"<main></main>"#
);
```